# Expression must have pointer-to-class-type

Tags: c++, list, pointers, struct, iterator

I have a struct "MachineState", and I created a list of type "MachineState*". When I try to iterate through the list, I Keep getting "

```
error C2839: invalid return type 'MachineState **' for overloaded 'operator ->
```

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 10. I googled the error and all i could find out was "The -> operator must return a class, struct, or union, or a reference to one."

```
Struct MachineState
{

   template <typename MachineTraits>
   friend class Machine;

   enum Facing { UP, RIGHT, DOWN, LEFT};
   MachineState()
    : m_ProgramCounter(1)
    , m_ActionsTaken(0)
    , m_Facing(UP)
    , m_Test(false)
    , m_Memory(nullptr)
    ,x(0)
    ,y(0)
    ,point1(25, 10)
    ,point2(10, 40)
    ,point3(40, 40)
    
   { }


   int m_ProgramCounter;
   int m_ActionsTaken;

   Facing m_Facing;
    bool m_Test;
    int x;
    int y;
    Point point1;
    Point point2;
    Point point3;

};
```

I declare the list as

```
 std::list<MachineState*> zombs;
```

Here is where I try to iterate through my list and i keep getting the error, on the "it->point1" saying  that the expression must have a pointer to class type.

```
        for(std::list<MachineState*>::iterator it = zombs.begin(); it != zombs.end(); it++)
         {
            Point points[3] = {it->point1, it->point2, it->point3};
            Point* pPoints = points;
            SolidBrush brush(Color(255, 255, 0, 0));
            m_GraphicsImage.FillPolygon(&brush, pPoints,3);
         }
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`it` is an **iterator to a *pointer*** to a `MachineState`.

You need to dereference the iterator **and then** the pointer.

```
Point points[3] = {(*it)->point1, (*it)->point2, (*it)->point3};
```

**Edit:**

*Dereferencing* means *getting the thing that it's referring to*.

Dereferencing is done with the `*` or `->` operator.

If `it` were a `MachineState`, you could use `it.point1`

If `it` were a **pointer** to a `MachineState`, you could use `it->point1` or `(*it).point1`

If `it` were a **iterator** to a `MachineState`, you could also use `it->point1` or `(*it).point1`

Since `it` is an **iterator to a pointer** to a `MachineState`, you must use `(*it)->point1` or `(**it).point1`

Comment: That's the correct answer. I'm sorry, i'm a beginner in c++. would you telling me what you mean by dereferencing? Thank you so much for the answer